# Удаление файлов из директории с поддиректориями

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Необходимо по запросу очищать определенную директорию от файлов и из всех дочерних директорий. Попытался написать следующим образом:

```
<?
function cld($pa)
{
    $dir = opendir($pa);
    while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if(is_dir($file) && $file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            cld($pa.'/'.$file);
        }
        else if (!is_dir($file) && $file != "." && $file != "..") 
        { 
            unlink($pa.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
}
cld('./media');

?>
```

На первое вхождение все срабатывает корректно. То есть из корневой директории и из дочерних файлы удаляются, но директории дочерних директорий начинают определяться как файлы и соответственно не очищаются.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот вариант с осторожностью, чтобы не удалить чего-то лишнего. Функция удаляет все папки и файлы, в том числе и файл, из под которого она была запущена:

```
<?php

function rm($dir) {
    $dh = opendir($dir);

    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            is_dir($dir .'/'. $file) ? rm($dir .'/'. $file) : unlink($dir .'/'. $file);
        }
    }

    closedir($dh);

    return rmdir($dir) ? true : false;
}

rm('.');

echo 'Directory does not contain any files!';
```

Comment: @BwehaaFox рекомендую сделать резервную копию перед её запуском. **UPD:** забыл добавить удаление директорий _(подправил ответ)_

Comment: мне как раз  и нужно удалять вместе с самим файлом, спасибо за решение.